Overriding Spring datasource properties for integrationTest with testcontainer DB credentials in SpringBoot application
I have setup a gradle Spring boot application where I am trying to execute the build process using a testcontainer.
Here is what I wanted to achieve when I run .\gradlew clean build

Start a MySql testcontainer

Use that testcontainer DB credentials and apply DB migrations using
Liquibase

Execute generateJooq task connecting to the same testcontainer DB.

Execute the integrationTest gradle task against the same
testcontainer DB.


Now I am having issue on the 4th step where I wanted to use the testcontainer DB dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword and dbDriver to connect to the testcontainer DB while executing the integrationTest gradle task.
Basically I have a resource folder under intergationTest which has 'application-dev.properties' file where it loads the configurations from AWS secrets and param store for the service which includes spring.datasource.username, spring.datasource.password & spring.datasource.url as well.
I am looking for an option to override those threes values with the testcontainer DB credentials.
Here is what I have in the application-dev.properties
spring.config.import=aws-parameterstore:/dev/my-test-app/,aws-secretsmanager:dev/my-test-app

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health

Here is my build.gradle file
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle'
}
group = 'com.test'
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}
ext {
    dbUrl = ''
    dbUsername = ''
    dbPassword = ''
    dbDriver = ''
}


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:${springCloudAwsVersion}")
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${testcontainersVersion}")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-parameter-store'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:+'
   
    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    integrationTestImplementation 'org.testcontainers:mysql'
}

apply from: "gradle/dbcontainer.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/liquibase.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/jooq.gradle"
apply from: 'project-build.gradle

Here is my dbcontainer.gradle
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer;

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:${testcontainersVersion}"
        classpath "org.testcontainers:mysql:${testcontainersVersion}"
        classpath "com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.4.0"
    }
}
def mysqlContainer = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.36").withDatabaseName("lmsdb")

tasks.register('startMySQLContainer') {
    doLast {
        mysqlContainer.start()

        project.ext.dbUrl = mysqlContainer.getJdbcUrl()
        project.ext.dbUsername = mysqlContainer.getUsername()
        project.ext.dbPassword = mysqlContainer.getPassword()
        project.ext.dbDriver = mysqlContainer.getDriverClassName()
        println("--- MySql Test container started successfully with URL : ${project.ext.dbUrl}")
    }
}
tasks.register('stopMySqlContainer') {
    doLast {
        if (mysqlContainer) {
            mysqlContainer.stop()
            println("----MySql Test container stopped successfully")
        }
    }
}
// Ensure the integrationTest uses the same container and stops it after
tasks.named('integrationTest').configure {
    dependsOn 'generateJooq'
    finalizedBy 'stopMySqlContainer'
}
// Ensure stopMySqlContainer runs after integrationTest
tasks.named('integrationTest').configure {
    finalizedBy 'stopMySqlContainer'
}

Here is my liquibase.gradle
configurations {
    liquibaseRuntime.extendsFrom runtimeClasspath
}
dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
    runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    implementation 'info.picocli:picocli:4.7.6'
}
tasks.named('startMySQLContainer').configure {
    doLast {
        liquibase {
            activities {
                main {
                    changelogFile 'liquibase/db1/tc_changelog.yml'
                    url project.ext.dbUrl
                    username project.ext.dbUsername
                    password project.ext.dbPassword
                }
            }
            runList = 'main'
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('update') {
    dependsOn ':startMySQLContainer'
}

Here is my jooq.gradle
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqGenerate

buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:${jooqPluginVersion}"
    }
    ext {
        // use jOOQ version defined in Spring Boot
        jooqVersion = dependencyManagement.importedProperties['jooq.version']
    }
    configurations.classpath {
        // Enforce the jOOQ configuration XML schema version
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            if (requested.group == 'org.jooq' && requested.name.startsWith('jooq')) {
                useVersion jooqVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqPlugin


// JOOQ dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
    jooqGenerator 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    jooqGenerator 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple'
    jooqGenerator 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    jooqGenerator "org.testcontainers:mysql"
    jooqGenerator 'org.testcontainers:jdbc'
}
// Configure JOOQ
jooq {
    version = jooqVersion

    configurations {
        main {
            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'lmsdb'
                    }
                    generate {
                        records = true
                        immutablePojos = true
                        fluentSetters = true
                        javaTimeTypes = false
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = "com.test.sample.db"
                    }
                     = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.register('configureJooq') {
    dependsOn 'startMySQLContainer', 'update'
    doLast {
        jooq.configurations.main {
            generationTool {
                jdbc {
                    url = project.ext.dbUrl
                    user = project.ext.dbUsername
                    password = project.ext.dbPassword
                    driver = project.ext.dbDriver
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Configure the JVM used for the JOOQ code generation process
tasks.withType(JooqGenerate).configureEach {
    javaExecSpec = { JavaExecSpec s ->
        s.systemProperties 
    }
}
tasks.named('generateJooq') {
    dependsOn 'configureJooq'
}

Thanks in advance. Please let me know how I can override and use those values to execute the integrationTest task.

I was able to address my problem on my own :) .
